# PHP, cURL Posting array?

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to use cURL to login.

The HTML from the login page is doing something I never saw.

```
<input type="text" name="user_session[login]"/>
<input type="password" name="user_session[password]"/>
```

I have tried to:

```
user_session[login]=blablabla&user_session[password]=blablabla
```

But nothing, any idea?

Comment: So an array will be constructed on the other side containing keys `login` and `password` with their corresponding values, so what's the problem? Also search SO first on logging in with cURL, you need to add ALL inputs in the form and work your way down which inputs aren't used/necessary.

Comment: @dbf but simply doing `user_session[login]` will make `PHP` understand it is a `array`? Won't it be treated as a string?

Comment: In short, everything you send through HTTP is binary, everything in binary will be converted to a string (not always, but in most cases), the structure of the string will be interpreted whatever it needs to be, array, object, int etc. And yes it will understand that this will end up as an array.

Comment: @dbf got it...so maybe CSRF protection?

Comment: might be, but even that can be forged, it just takes a lot of time. Not so long ago I saw an article about someone forging the creation of cookies through an equivalent use of cURL login procedures .. though his attempt was to steal sessions from active users, but it can also be used to accept the login and request further info. I'll post it here when I find the article. But are you sure that's the problem? Have you tried sniffed POST information when transmitting the form? Firebug for example can do that easily.

Comment: yes, I traced all the information to access the site. Even when I do post it returns me the error page

Comment: it would seem that one is hacking if one does not know the owner of this site... no?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you URL-encode the keys. I don't think those brackets are safe. PHP will parse those arguments as an array, but what the script does shouldn't matter if you're just trying to simulate a form submission. If you use the PHP 5 function `http_build_query` with the array `['user_session' => ['login' => 'NAME', 'password' => 'PASS']]` it should return the query string you need, properly escaped (which can be appended to the URL after `?` or used as POST data with `curl_setopt($resource, CURL_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($args))`).

If it still doesn't work, post the whole form; there may be some other problem with your submission besides the brackets.